# String.Format with null values C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I want to format an address. Here is my code:

```
address = String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}",
                        postalAddress.Line1,
                        postalAddress.Line2,
                        postalAddress.Line3,
                        postalAddress.Line4,
                        postalAddress.Suburb,
                        postalAddress.StateCode,
                        postalAddress.Pcode);
```

Unfortunately this produces `116 Knox St, , , , Watson, ACT, 2602` when Line2, Line3, Line4 are null. How can I handle the nulls to get a results like `116 Knox St, Watson, ACT, 2602`?

Comment: `StringBuilder` + `if` ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: do you know what the `StringBuilder` is? How about `if`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like this accomplishes your purpose much more concisely.

```
string[] data = new[] { 
    postalAddress.Line1, 
    postalAddress.Line2, 
    postalAddress.Line3, 
    postalAddress.Line4, 
    postalAddress.Suburb, 
    postalAddress.StateCode, 
    postalAddress.Pcode 
};

string address = string.Join(", ", 
                             data.Where(e => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.  This is not going to be very efficient but should work ;)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
List<string> addressParts = new List<string> { postalAddress.Line1, postalAddress.Line2, postalAddress.Line3, postalAddress.Line4, postalAddress.Suburb, postalAddress.StateCode, postalAddress.Pcode };
addressParts.ForEach(x => sb.Append(String.IsNullOrEmpty(x) ? "" : ", " + x));
string address = sb.ToString().Trim(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend `McAden` solution, it's elegant and solves your problem nicely. Stated below is one option on how to use the `StringBuilder`, it's very verbose compared to the others.

As stated in the comments you can use the `StringBuilder` and a series of `if` statements. Thsi code can be cleaned up nicely but to let you play with it and understand what is going on, here is an example:

```
var postalAddress = new {
    Line1 = "116 Knox St",
    Line2 = "",
    Line3 = "",
    Line4 = "",
    Suburb = "Watson",
    StateCode = "ACT",
    Pcode = "2602",
};
var builder = new StringBuilder();

builder.AppendFormat("{0}, ", postalAddress.Line1);

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postalAddress.Line2))
{
    builder.AppendFormat("{0}, ", postalAddress.Line2);
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postalAddress.Line3))
{
    builder.AppendFormat("{0}, ", postalAddress.Line3);
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postalAddress.Line4))
{
    builder.AppendFormat("{0}, ", postalAddress.Line4);
}

builder.AppendFormat("{0}, ", postalAddress.Suburb);
builder.AppendFormat("{0}, ", postalAddress.StateCode);
builder.AppendFormat("{0}", postalAddress.Pcode);

var result = builder.ToString();
```

When you print the `result` variable you will now have the following result:

`116 Knox St, Watson, ACT, 2602`

Basically you can use `AppendFormat` to append the string in a formatted manner and you can experiment and play around with this until it behaves as you like, then you can refactor it to be a bunch less lines thane this!

Answer (score 0):

What about a one liner Regex to remove the duplicate , and spaces.

```
address = String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}",
                        postalAddress.Line1,
                        postalAddress.Line2,
                        postalAddress.Line3,
                        postalAddress.Line4,
                        postalAddress.Suburb,
                        postalAddress.StateCode,
                        postalAddress.Pcode);

address = Regex.Replace(address, @"(,\s)+", @"$1");
```